# Switch OVS with version 2.5.5 how many rules can handle?

Tags: sdn

I am working with OVS switchs and I want to know how many rules or flows they can support.

Thanks

Comment: Probably more than you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your time is something that I will never be able to give you back.

Comment: As you can see by the answer below, I was essentially correct.  It's a software switch, and I couldn't think of any good reason why the number of rules would be arbitrarily limited, other than performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find its limitations in [OVS doc limit section](http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vswitchd.8.txt):

Kernel flows limit:

> Kernel flows are limited only by memory available to the kernel.
>   Performance  will  degrade  beyond  1,048,576  kernel  flows per
>   bridge with a 32-bit kernel, beyond 262,144 with a  64-bit  kernel

OpenFlow flows limit:

> OpenFlow flows are limited only by available memory. Performance
>   is linear in the number of unique wildcard patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the link to the site.